Desktop > Clean Up By > Size : The resulting arrangement makes no sense. Am I missing something?
If I run the action:
Desktop > Clean Up By > Size :
The resulting arrangement makes no discernible sense. Am I missing something?
I have had this problem persist through many macOS updates.
I do not know if it is just my computer, if I don't understand what's going on, or if this is a more common problem.
It is only mostly arranged vertically by file type, but that doesn't make sense because there should not be a string of multiple folders in a row when various other files have sizes that should break that sequence up. The folders also aren't even in the right order.
Finder's sort by size feature still works perfectly well.
Desktop > Clean Up By : Also works perfectly fine for every other variable.

How exactly is it being arranged?  Remember, we can’t see over your shoulder so you need to provide clear details or a screen shot so we can be on the same page.

@Allan - You're absolutely right. I haven't tried uploading media yet. -- Before I do upload, I'll need to make an informative and censored screenshot. Or I can just repopulate my desktop with new files, if so, what would be diagnostically helpful to see? -- My desktop won't reflect file size at all. So I imagine an included finder window list sorted by size would do the trick, no?

The Finder window of the Desktop (or another folder) in list view could work
